# Правильность популярного выражения для функции копирования строк в языке Си { while (*dest++ = *src++) }

Tags: c

Начал читать учебник "Программирование: Введение в профессию" Том №2 "Системы и сети" автора А.В. Столярова, в котором рассматривается язык программирования Си. В теме про указатели и строковые массивы (стр.96) есть небольшой пример реализации процедуры копирования из одной строки в другую. Собственно так выглядит код (на стр.94 есть еще один пример):

```
    void stringCopy(char* dest, const char* src)
    {
        while ((*dest++ = *src++));    
    }
```

Автор настаивает, что в коде есть ошибка. Причем сам пример часто мелькает в интернете в качестве "суперкороткого решения", и автор относится к этому отрицательно. Сам же автор конкретной ошибки не указывает, однако просит разобраться (для себя), лишь намекая на побочный эффект, который легко не заметить.
[image: Вот что автор пишет.]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот так выглядит правильный пример кода автора учебника:

```
     while (*src)
     {
         *dest = *src;
         dest++;
         src++;
     }
     *dest = '\0'
```

Собственно я искал хоть какое-то упоминание о ошибке в этом коде, но никто даже не интересовался, кроме как принципом работы кода. В общем если разобраться в приоритетах операций - все становится на свои места (я так сначала думал с разгону):

1.Оказывается что постфиксный инкремент/декремент имеют отличную от префиксных аналогов реализацию. Что точно уж объясняет работу ошибочного кода. Я проверил он работает 100%. https://ravesli.com/urok-40-inkrement-dekrement-pobochnye-effekty/

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void stringCopy(char* dest, const char* src)
{
    while ((*dest++ = *src++));// почему-то неправильная запись с ошибкой (хотя все работает)
    /*
    Правильная запись
    while (*src)
    {
        *dest = *src;
        dest++;
        src++;
    }
    *dest = '\0';
    */
}
int main()
{
    char* src = malloc(15);
    char* dest = malloc(15);
    *(src + 0) = '\0';
    *(src + 1) = 'e';
    *(src + 2) = 'a';
    *(src + 3) = 'r';
    *(src + 4) = '!';
//дальше не продолжал инициализацию - Visual Studio туда помещает 
//мусор без нулей
    
    stringCopy(dest, src);
//вот тут я поставил точку останова в дебаггере - мои указатели 
//ссылаются на нулевые строки (значит копирование успешно прошло при нулевой строке и значит что ошибка не в операторе постфиксного инкремента)
    free(src);
    free(dest);
}
```

2.Наконец вроде бы разобрался с понятием "леводопустимых" выражений (стр 87). Получается, что уникальность реализации постфиксных инкремента и декремента имеет прямую связь с этим понятием "леводопустимости"? Или это отдельно? Чтобы уже разобраться совсем совсем.

В итоге не понятно, есть ли там ошибка или нету.
Получается что проблема в наглядности этого кода и лучше писать все красиво по полочкам, ибо никогда не знаешь что стукнет в голову компилятору или сложно анализировать код? А ошибка придумана - чтобы сломать мозг тому кто будет ее искать и привести его к этому выводу?

Upd: ошибки там нет. Ошибка была в примере на стр. 94 (по видимости автора ошибкой является то, что длина высчитывается с учетом знака окончания строки, хотя это даже не правило). Просто мне показалось из-за стиля его заметок в виде крестика, что там тоже должна быть ошибка. Просто автор пытался показать, что так делать не стоит. Компактность кода в этом случае приводит к сложности понимания происходящего.

Upd: продолжив дальнейшее изучение книги я наткнулся на стр.100-103 параграф "Точки следования (sequence points). У меня конечно нет столько опыта, хотелось бы услышать имеет ли место в данной ситуации то, о чем там говорится. Ну и так как никто не ответил о "леводопустимых выражениях" - может и о них кто-то скажет в данной ситуации.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134731/discussion-on-question-by-artem------).

Comment: Первый код гарантированно выполняет ++, а значит никогда не возвращает 0 (впрочем, это проще заметить представив пустую строку в качестве аргумента). Отсюда, если подумать, можно понять, что возвращаемое значение всегда на 1 больше нужного. Во втором коде проблемы вообще не вижу. Инкрементить указатель на 1 дальше конца массива стандартом разрешено. А с точками следования вроде делать нечего, поскольку каждая переменная используется ровно 1 раз за выражение.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, проблема в том, что код не проверяет размер аллоцированной памяти, и скорее всего приведёт к UB. Поэтому просто вызвать `stringCopy` недостаточно, нужно ещё и подсчитать размер исходной строки (а это ещё один пробег по ней, если только размер не хранится отдельно).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Давайте отрефакторим:

```
void stringCopy(char* dest, const char* src)
{
    while ((*dest++ = *src++));    
}
```

a. Убираем лишние скобки ставим новые чтобы документировать порядок применения операторов:

```
void stringCopy(char* dest, const char* src)
{
    while (*(dest++) = *(src++));    
}
```

b. Разбираем цикл `while`:

```
void stringCopy(char* dest, const char* src)
{
    while (1) {    
        if (!(*(dest++) = *(src++)))
            break;
    }    
}
```

c. Разбираем условие в `if`:

```
void stringCopy(char* dest, const char* src)
{
    while (1) {
        char c = (*(dest++) = *(src++));    
        if (!c)
            break;
    }    
}
```

d. Выносим инкременты из присваивания:

```
void stringCopy(char* dest, const char* src)
{
    while (1) {
        char c = (*dest = *src);
        dest++;
        src++;    
        if (!c)
            break;
    }    
}
```

e. Заносим инкременты в `if`:

```
void stringCopy(char* dest, const char* src)
{
    while (1) {
        char c = (*dest = *src);
        if (!c) {
            dest++;
            src++;    
            break;
        } else {
            dest++;
            src++;    
        }
    }    
}
```

f. Инкременты перед `break` не меняют смысл программы. Убираем их:

```
void stringCopy(char* dest, const char* src)
{
    while (1) {
        char c = (*dest = *src);
        if (!c) {
            break;
        } else {
            dest++;
            src++;    
        }
    }    
}
```

g. Меняем условие в `if`:

```
void stringCopy(char* dest, const char* src)
{
    while (1) {
        *dest = *src;
        if (!(*src)) {
            break;
        } else {
            dest++;
            src++;    
        }
    }    
}
```

h. Заносим присваивание в `if`:

```
void stringCopy(char* dest, const char* src)
{
    while (1) {
        if (!(*src)) {
            *dest = *src;
            break;
        } else {
            *dest = *src;
            dest++;
            src++;    
        }
    }    
}
```

i. Уточняем условие в `if` и присваивание перед `break`:

```
void stringCopy(char* dest, const char* src)
{
    while (1) {
        if (*src == '\0') {
            *dest = '\0';
            break;
        } else {
            *dest = *src;
            dest++;
            src++;    
        }
    }    
}
```

j. Присваивание перед `break` выносим из цикла:

```
void stringCopy(char* dest, const char* src)
{
    while (1) {
        if (*src == '\0') {
            break;
        } else {
            *dest = *src;
            dest++;
            src++;    
        }
    }    
    *dest = '\0';
}
```

k. Убираем `if`:

```
void stringCopy(char* dest, const char* src)
{
    while (*src != '\0') {
        *dest = *src;
        dest++;
        src++;    
    }    
    *dest = '\0';
}
```

l. Меняем условие `while`:

```
void stringCopy(char* dest, const char* src)
{
    while (*src) {
        *dest = *src;
        dest++;
        src++;    
    }    
    *dest = '\0';
}
```

Получили правильный с точки зрения автора учебника вариант. Каждый шаг сохраняет семантику программы. Если вы сомневаетесь в каком-то шаге, комментируйте, разберёмся.

Автор может упомянуть что в конце работы оригинальной процедуры указатели `src` и `dest` указывают на элементы за концами строк. Язык `C` специально разрешает указателям указывать на элемент следующий за концом массива. Этот указатель нельзя разыменовывать, но этого и не происходит.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный разбор! Это мне было понятно изначально. Просто почему-то мне показалось что автор уверен, что в коде есть ошибка, на что он "мягко" намекнул крестиком возле кода. И я долго искал там ошибку. А ошибка была в предыдущем его примере, с которого он плавно перешел к рассматриваемому. В общем я искал ошибку где ее нету. Спасибо за потраченное время всем участникам. Мне стыдно)

Comment: Вы задали хороший вопрос, демонстрирующий сложность синтаксиса и семантики программ на `C`. Стыдиться нечего.

Comment: @Artem, для изучения С достаточно прочесть K&R (и м.б. /usr/include/*.h -)) (на всех остальных авторов можно не тратить свое время)

Comment: Спасибо за совет) ну просто думаю уже осилить эту книженцию чтобы было с чем сравнивать.

Comment: @Artem, надо бы ответ принять.

Comment: Я приму, но это не ответ. Просто он единственный.